# how to create project id incrementally in sql based on identity column

Tags: sql

I have a project table:

```
CREATE TABLE DOC.BRAND 
(
    ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
    project_id varchar(150) ,
    project_name varchar(250) ,
)
```

For example, `project_id` should be PRJ001, PRJ002 based on identity column value as shown here:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+
| ID | project_id  | project_name  |
+----+-------------+---------------+
| 1  | PRJ001      | PROJECT1      |
| 2  | PRJ002      | PROJECT2      |
+----+-------------+---------------+
```

How we can achieve that using a stored procedure or is there any table-level setting?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SQL Server (which seems likely based on the syntax), you can use a computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE DOC.BRAND (
    ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
    project_id as ('PRJ' + format(id, '000')),
    project_name varchar(250)
);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0507f7decdcf49837c86be320e2470c7) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I'd note you'll have problems once you get to Ids over 999...

Comment: What is best idea to overcome 999issue?

Comment: @Bhushan . . . Add more digits to the `project_id`.  Or just use the `id`.  You don't really need to format it as a string.

Comment: How to convert ID column into varchar as Project_ID as ('PRJ' + id)